# Signed char data range

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am working on coding exercises for C++ beginner on Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) with Visual Studio Community 2019. I would like to know what is the data range signed char can hold.

Firstly, my understanding is as below:

***"Signed char is character data type that consumes 7 bits of the memory with sign bit. Range -128 to 127."***

However I don't get any error compiling and executing the code which includes below lines.

```
// signed char consumes 7 bits with sign bit. range -128 to 127
signed char characterA = -1786;
```

Why -1786, which is out of range (-128 to 127), the datatype "signed char" can hold?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings: *warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'signed char'* and *warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value*.

Comment: Or try using `signed char characterA{-1786}`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for your answer.
[Compiler Warning (level 1) C4305](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4305?view=msvc-160)
[Compiler Warning (level 2) C4309](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4309?view=msvc-160)

Comment: The clang-cl (LLVM) compiler (available in Visual Studio 2019) does rather better, IMHO: *warning : implicit conversion from 'int' to 'signed char' changes value from -1786 to 6 [-Wconstant-conversion]*

Comment: @AdrianMole The current setting of my Visual Studio is Warning Level 3 so it actually covered the warnings you pointed out. I compiled again and got below warnings.
: warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'signed char'
: warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value

I don't actually understand what's happening so I printed the value out on the console, and I got 

characterA = ♠

It seems automatically the data I assigned "-1786" seems to be modified (truncated).

Comment: @jkb Thank you for your answer! I tried your suggestion and got the warning. I appreciate your help.
error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'signed char' requires a narrowing conversion

Comment: `std::cout << (int)characterA << ‘\n’;` will show you the stored value. Try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the answer. I got 6. On the other hand I calculated manually then I got -6. 
-1786(10) = -11011111010(2) ---truncate to 8 bit ---> 11111010(2) = -6(10)
How do I misunderstand calculation?

Comment: @yurachika2020 -1786(10)=1111 ...（many 1111）... 1111 1001 0000 0110(2) ---truncate to 8 bit ---> 00000110 (2)
You could verify your calculation results with a binary calculator.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thank you for your comment! I manually re-calculated. I forgot that I had to use 2's complement to convert negative decimal number to binary. So, given the number −1786, the binary number for +1786:
110 1111 1010

The complement of this is:
001 0000 0101

Adding one to this gives:
001 0000 0110

Truncate to 8 bit gives:
0000 0110

In decimal it's 6!